# Slack API and custom slack app always get invalid-oauth with botkit framework

Tags: slack-api, slack, botkit

Ì'm running around a boring problem.
Since few days, I'm always getting `invalid_oauth` from slack API...
I'm using Botkit framework, node.js server this is my debug :

`info: ** Starting webserver on port 3000
info: ** Serving webhook endpoints for Slash commands and outgoing webhooks at: http://MY_HOST:3000/slack/receive
info: ** Serving login URL: http://MY_HOST:3000/login
info: ** Serving oauth return endpoint: http://MY_HOST:3000/oauth
info: ** API CALL: https://slack.com/api/rtm.start
debug: rtm.start { no_unreads: true,
  simple_latest: true,
  token: 'xoxb-81934967667-UOJKkxYnIf0xZJ9cJspwoAOC' }
debug: Got response null {"ok":false,"error":"invalid_auth"}
Error connecting bot to Slack: invalid_auth`

I'm launching the app with :
`clientId=xxx.xxx clientSecret=xxx port=3000 node bot.js`

I have my custom slack App configured with oauth endpoint returned by botkit debug console, localtunnel forwarding to my local machine, one bot configured in the App.

Any ideas ? I'm sure I'm not very far from the solution...

thanks a lot for any help.

Comment: Can you share your code please? Your bot is trying to connect to the RTM api, and is failing with the wrong credentials. But that debug message at the very bottom, the `Error connecting bot to slack` is language from outdated examples, and does not appear anywhere itself in the latest version of the framework. If you show me the example you're working from, I'm sure I can help.